# Google Pub/Sub message took ~5 minutes to be published. Why is that?

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Cloud Function that is publishing a Cloud Pub/Sub message. However this test message takes ~5 minutes to be published and consumed by a test subscription.

Is this a normal timing for that? I actually was expecting it to be way faster and let's say more responsive. I'd like to initialize a user in my database when my Auth0 hook (post-registration) triggers the Cloud Function endpoint.

Best case the user init should happen before the user visits the website after registration therefore speed is somewhat crucial.

Here is the function code (Java):

```java
public class UserInit implements HttpFunction {
  @Override
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws Exception {
    String projectId = "app-platform";
    String topicId = "user-init";
    final TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
    final Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
    System.out.println("project: " + projectId);
    System.out.println("topic: " + topicId);
    final PubsubMessage message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
        .putAttributes("test", "test")
        .build();
    final ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(message);
    ApiFutures.addCallback(messageIdFuture, new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {
      public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
        System.out.println("published with message id: " + messageId);
      }

      public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("failed to publish: " + t);
      }
    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
  }
}
```

Here are the relevant logs:

```
2021-03-20T12:29:47.486387599Zuser-initlo8xln5ztgq3 Function execution started
2021-03-20T12:29:57.947Zuser-initlo8xln5ztgq3 project: app-platform
2021-03-20T12:29:57.949Zuser-initlo8xln5ztgq3 topic: user-init
2021-03-20T12:29:59.551220278Zuser-initlo8xln5ztgq3 Function execution took 12065 ms, finished with status code: 200
2021-03-20T12:35:13.145Zuser-initlo8xln5ztgq3 published with message id: 2139319306781573
```

The first thing is `Function execution took 12065 ms` which surprises me. The function took *12 seconds* for the execution. That is quite some time imho.
The really annoying thing however is the time between function execution and the Pub/Sub callback

```
2021-03-20T12:29:59 // execution
2021-03-20T12:35:13 // callback print message
```

This is ~5 minutes that passed. I can confirm that by the Pub/Sub monitoring and also my test subscription where I was executing a "Pull" several times after I expected the message to be already published. In all cases I can confirm that the time from function execution and the discovery of the pub/sub message took as already mentioned ~5 minutes.

So I wonder is this the expected behaviour and I am just surprised since I use Pub/Sub the first time or am I right that something is a bit odd here?

Also here is my `cloudbuild.yaml` setup and therefore the configuration of my function:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
      - gcloud
      - functions
      - deploy
      - user-init
      - --runtime=java11
      - --region=europe-west3
      - --source=./user-init
      - --entry-point=com.app.functions.UserInit
      - --allow-unauthenticated
      - --trigger-http
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
      - gcloud
      - alpha
      - functions
      - add-iam-policy-binding
      - user-init
      - --region=europe-west3
      - --member=allUsers
      - --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
```

**Edit 1**

I try to wait for the concurrent task with `.wait()` after the `publish()` call.

Relevant changes look like this:

```java
    final Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
        .setBatchingSettings(Publisher.Builder.getDefaultBatchingSettings())
        .build();
    final PubsubMessage message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
        .putAttributes("test", "test")
        .build();
    publisher.publish(message).wait();
```

However these error occur as a result of using `wait()`

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker$NotFoundHandler.handle(Invoker.java:392)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
```

Comment: On the "Function took 12 seconds to complete" ... I believe that message is logged by Cloud Functions.   Two immediate thoughts (guesses) come to mind ... the first is that you may have experienced cold start latency.  The 12 seconds may have included the time to spin up a JVM, initialize the framework and then invoke the function.   The second thought is that you aren't allowed to do work in the background.   Am not familiar with ApiFutureCallback ... but are you anticipating work to be performed after the return from the Cloud Function entry point?

Comment: @Kolban no I don't want to put any business logic into the callback. I just used ApiFunctionCallback to get an idea of the time until the message is being published by the function

Comment: @Kolban I am fine with that 12 seconds - maybe I can speed that up by using a python script instead. However what I do not like is that ~5min of the message publication

Answer (score 1):

Your Cloud Functions is really executed in 12s, and replied HTTP 200 code. Then the CPU is throttled because, outside request processing, your Cloud Functions doesn't require CPU.

You have less than 5% of CPU allowed to your Cloud Functions, very few and it takes time to execute the callback with so few CPU.

Indeed, you reply HTTP 200 before waiting the effective message publication. Add this line at the end of your function

```
messageIdFuture.wait();
```

Wait the end of concurrent threads. You will see it will be far more efficient!

---

You also need to know that the [Cloud Functions performance (and thus pricing) depends on the quantity of memory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time). By default, you have 256Mb of memory -> 400Mhz of compute processing: Starting your Cloud Functions + JVM with only 400Mhz, single core CPU, takes, indeed time (12s). And you can also understand that 5% of that to handle the callback, can take minutes!

So, increase the Cloud Functions memory to increase your Cloud Functions performances

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited my question with the suggestion of your's. I raised the memory to 4096MB and added the `.wait()` method at the end of my publish routine. Unfortunately an error occured due that changes. I have a hard time to interpret that to be fair